# How to extract List - movi tag from AVI files on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, libavcodec, libavformat, libavg

I am trying to retrieve RIFF data from AVI file in my iOS app.  I tried to convert AVI file to NSDATA and then i have converted to NSASCIIStringEncoding and i am getting all tag as string but how to retrieve particular tag,in this case I am getting all data but as there is lots data inside it, it is tough to get data from specific tags. I want to retrieve specific data from the specific tag.  Here I have enclosed screenshot which shows how data looks like on Windows computer. I have used software named AVI master to see RIFF data in windows computer .As you can see in the screenshot, I will need data associated with 03tx tag. 
I tried all possible ways to read chunk by chunk and also tried Libavformat library, but no success. Is there any other way to get RIFF data associated with AVI file? 
Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Have you written *any* code to parse / extract *anything* from the file so far?

Comment: No i have search a lot but i am not able to find anything to related to ios for AVI. If you have any document link please suggest me.

Comment: Trivial solution that comes to my mind is to have a back-end side for doing such stuff in python. Why reinvent the wheel? Here are [some](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir-parser/) [solutions](https://github.com/aurelpjetri/python_avi_parser) for parsing `.AVI` in Python.
Or, you may be could take a look at [this library written in C](https://github.com/raystubbs/libraff) and then you could use it in [Swift](https://theswiftdev.com/2018/01/15/how-to-call-c-code-from-swift/).

Comment: Yes i know it can easily done from backend but we need to done this on client side.
Our requirement is get data from video file while playing.